# Bounding the Number of Roots of Polynomial Modulo p

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, roots

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. Can we bound the number of solutions to the following equation:

$$(x+1)^q \equiv x^q + 1 \pmod{p}$$
where $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} ?$

Comment: $(x+1)^q-x^q-1$ is a polynomial of degree $q-1$, so $\min(p,q-1)$. What do you expect exactly ?

Comment: The results of a quick test program suggest that for every prime $p > 3$, there will be infinitely many primes $q\,$ for which the number of solutions is $p$ (i.e., every $x$ works), and infinitely many primes $q\,$ for which the only solutions are $x=0\,$ and $x = -1$.

Comment: @quasi sure, infinitely many $q$, since it is periodic $\bmod p-1$. So a better answer is at most $d-1$ solutions where $d\equiv q \bmod p-1$.